# Is task.getResult().isEmpty() refers document is not available and task.getResult().exists() refers document is available in firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making firestore query and based on result exists or not i need to take further decisions.
I am already knowing that such document does not exist in collection which satisfy query criteria. I am just testing....

Now i am facing following problem

```
    System.out.println("inside check referrer");
    db.collection("referral")
            .whereEqualTo("refereeMobile", mobileNumber).limit(1)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        System.out.println("task is succcessful");
                        if (task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println("tasks is empty");
                        }
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            System.out.println("hello");
                            if (document.exists()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                System.out.println(" user is referred");
                                Referral referral = document.toObject(Referral.class);
                                updateUserAndNavigateToHomeActivity(true, referral.getReferrerUid(), referral.getReferrerEmail());
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("document does not exist");
                                updateUserAndNavigateToHomeActivity(false, null, null);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

so i am able to print based on `if (task.getResult().isEmpty())` but i am not able to print anything when i check if `if (document.exists()){---print----}else {----print-----}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `task.getResult().isEmpty()` returns true, that means there are no documents in your result set.  Your `for` loop will never execute a single time, because there are no documents.  I'm not clear why you would expect there to be a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` to find.  If you want to find a document in the query, first create one that matches the query.

Comment: i want to find if any such document exist already which has same field value for a particular field before i save new record. However i understood your explanation correctly that although document.exists return false but i am not able to print because for loop is not running.... is there any better way to do ? thanks @Doug Stevenson

Comment: I am not very clear on what you are trying to accomplish.  There's not much you can do with the empty results of a query.